# How can I beat Classic 9.0 on Smash 3DS?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I'm stuck on Classic 9.0. I'm good enough to beat Classic 8.5, but every time I do 9.0, it's always a wii fit trainer who kills me right before master and crazy hand. Any tips would be useful, I'm using Shulk with +50 attack, -71 defense, and +33 speed. My custom moves for shulk are: Hyper Monado, Back Slash Charge, Advancing Air Slash, and Power vision. Once again, any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the wii fit trainer is what is bothering you, I'd recommend working on your spacing. If you can avoid her (or his) projectiles, she struggles to outdistance shulk's sword. Also try looking up what wii fit's hitboxes look like - I've heard she has weird ones.